# Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy and 6 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Tags: java, gradle

When i tried to create a new gradle project with 'gradle init' it just created "infinite" gradle daemons until my memory was full and i got following error after every daemon:

> 'Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy and 6 stopped Daemons could not be
> reused, use --status for details'

When i ran gradle --status for diagnostics i got following report:

> 'Unable to stop one of the daemons. The daemon may have crashed.'

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

this issue raised when build with incompatible gradle version andngradle plugin version
please check  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: what about kotlin-gradle-plugin:? Mine is `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"`

Comment: I started a bounty, please take a look